# how many birthdays of that person has been on the same day of the week

Tags: c#

I have a date of birth. i want to calculate how many times the birthday of that person has been on the same day of the week in which that person was born. so if he was born on Friday, then I want to count how many birthdays till now that fell on Friday.

```
public static int HowManyBirthDaysInSameDayOfWeek(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (DateTime d = dateOfBirth; d.Date <= DateTime.Today; d = d.AddYears(1))
    { 
         if (d.DayOfWeek == dateOfBirth.DayOfWeek)
         {
             counter++;
         }
     }

     return counter;
 }
```

Comment: public static int HowManyBirthDaysInSameDayOfWeek(DateTime dateOfBirth)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (DateTime d = dateOfBirth; d.Date <= DateTime.Today; d = d.AddYears(1))
            {
                if (d.DayOfWeek == dateOfBirth.DayOfWeek)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            return counter;

        }

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: this is what I have done so far

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: ok give me a minute to find out how to edit

Comment: And what is your question? Do you get any error? Any unexpected results? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried and where exactly you´ve got problems.

Comment: its an incorrect value, but it is very near, the correct value was 4 and it returned 5. i think its the boundaries of the iteration

Comment: the method was invoked with (10/03/1984 00:00:00)  expected correct answer (4)   my code returned (5)

Comment: It's counting the birth day and you're apparently not according to your comments.

Comment: Thanks for editing the code. @stuartd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will work for all birthdates, including February 29.

```
public static int HowManyBirthDaysInSameDayOfWeek(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    int iteration = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (DateTime d = dateOfBirth.AddYears(1); d.Date <= DateTime.Today; d = dateOfBirth.AddYears(++iteration))
    {
        if (d.DayOfWeek == dateOfBirth.DayOfWeek)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

*The key here is starting a year after the date of birth and always adding years relative to the birth date, rather than adding one year at a time. Otherwise February 29 doesn't calculate correctly. With this code, those born on February 29 will have their birthday on February 29 in leap years, and February 28 otherwise.*

Comment: Unfortunately while this might work, it's just a code dump and doesn't explain to the OP why his code doesn't work or why yours does.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for the feedback.

Comment: Also, I'd say it doesn't work for Feb 29th as they only occur once every 4 years (usually) so if a person were born on 29-Feb-1976 there should only be 10 birthdays.

Comment: (PS sorry I keep commenting on your answers - I promise I'm not stalking you!)

Comment: For people born on 29th Feb, my code will have their birthday as 29th Feb in leap years and 28th Feb in other years. The problem with the other solutions presented here is that they treat it as 28th Feb in **all** years.

Comment: Actually for people born on 29th Feb, they celebrate on 28th Feb, 1st Mar or every 4 years on 29th Feb - it's a [personal choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29#Born_on_February_29). I know this because I was born 3 hours after Feb 29th, phew!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ davidG , If I knew why my code doesn't work, I wouldn't have bothered the community of c# sharp.  Thanks for your code mjwills            the method was invoked with (20/08/1977 00:00:00)  expected (5) returned (6).

Comment: What makes you think it is 5 @RoyGuzman ? Don't 1983, 1988, 1994, 2005, 2011, 2016 all match?

Comment: Sure @DavidG , and my code reflects one of those options (Feb 29 in leap years, Feb 28 otherwise). The other solutions here will treat someone born on Feb 29 as if they were born on Feb 28 instead, and are thus invalid in terms of Feb 29 handling. **On a leap year, every other solution here will get the day of Feb 28th (when their actual birthday is Feb 29th).**

Comment: @RoyGuzman - that should return 6 - the same years mjwills wrote. Add a print at the beginning of the loop, before the if condition printing the year and day and see

Comment: you are absolutely right, I counted it manually :). I accepted your answer. Thanks mjwills

Comment: I am sorry guys if my questions lack the experience, all the questions I am posting are recommended exercises to prepare me to solve three methods tomorrow Friday the 21/7/2017. if I manage to solve those three methods tomorrow I will have a job offer and start the actual training as c# developer. I did not know anything about c# until 2 weeks ago. I am allowed to consult anyone and anything to solve those three methods, if you have few minutes to spare tomorrow to help me then here my email address roygad1978@gmail.com.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you meet the `if statement` also on the **first iteration** which is the day the person was born. Therefore your output is +1 than inteded.

Just subtract 1 from the counter when returning or start from the year after:

```
public static int HowManyBirthDaysInSameDayOfWeek(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (DateTime d = dateOfBirth.AddYears(1); d.Date <= DateTime.Today; d = d.AddYears(1))
    { 
         if (d.DayOfWeek == dateOfBirth.DayOfWeek)
         {
             counter++;
         }
     }    
     return counter;
 }
```

Comment: if I change the for loop to d= d.addDays(1) the return value was 1741.

Comment: @RoyGuzman - ya - I've noticed my mistake and added explanation about what to do instead

Answer (score 0):

```
for (DateTime d = dateOfBirth.AddYears(1); d.Date <= DateTime.Today; d = d.AddYears(1))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: @FordPerfect The loop shouldn't include the day of birth. However, my answer did not consider Feb.29. For complete solution see the accepted answer.